# Having issues with Djikstra's algorithm

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, dijkstra, path-traversal

Trying to implement Dijkstra's via the instructions in this article:

https://medium.com/@adriennetjohnson/a-walkthrough-of-dijkstras-algorithm-in-javascript-e94b74192026

My repl below:

https://repl.it/@Stylebender/DJIK#index.js

1. The actual Dijkstra method within the Graph class is throwing a not defined error. Just wondering is there a typo or something I did wrong on my end?
2. In any case, would this be a solid implementation of Dijkstra's?

Answer (score 1):

In the end change `findPathWithDijkstra("Fullstack", "Cafe Grumpy");` to `map.findPathWithDijkstra("Fullstack", "Cafe Grumpy");`

You have created findPathWithDijkstra in the Graph class so you need to call it through an object, in your case `map`

Comment: Oh wow I'm a moron. Thank you! Btw, is this a good implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: There may be, I'm no expert so you should probably wait for someone more experienced to answer that question. The algorithm however, seems fine to me. I don't see any extra steps and that's the one I studied in school so it's the only one I know.